# Sort permutation of N using 1 free swap and adjacent swaps

Tags: algorithm, sorting, permutation, mergesort

**Question:**

Given an array of N numbers contain a permutation of N. You have 2 types of swaps:

- Swap **any** 2 numbers of the array (you can only do this **once**)
- Swap adjacent numbers (you can do this many times)

What is the least number of swap to sort the array?

**Example:**

```
arr[] = {5, 3, 4, 2, 1}

answer: 3

Explaination:
 - Swap 5 and 1
 - Swap 4 and 2
 - Swap 3 and 2
```

**P/S:**

I think that we need to use the "free swap" first and then use merge sort. But I don't know how to use the the "free swap" so that the merge sort is minimum.

Comment: You meant bubble sort?

Comment: I would use the free swap on the 2 numbers that are the further appart.

Comment: @Tarik but sometimes it's not the optimal way

Comment: @Tarik bubble sort can have many "free swaps", this can only have one, and the rest is adjacent swaps

Comment: does the array can only contain 1 to N numbers?

Comment: @unglinh279 "Bubble sort, sometimes referred to as sinking sort, is a simple sorting algorithm that repeatedly steps through the list, compares *adjacent elements* and swaps them if they are in the wrong order." - Wikipedia

Comment: @Tarik yes. i think we can use bubble sort or merge sort after we use our "free swap" - which swap *any* 2 elements in the array

Comment: @BehdadAbdollahiMoghadam yes. the array can only contain 1 to N numbers

Comment: Is it ok to write the algorithm in python? @unglinh279

Comment: @BehdadAbdollahiMoghadam yes it's ok for any language

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just swap the number that is most left from where it should be with the one that is most right from where it should be.

So left would be index i where arr[i] - i is the maximum. And right would be index j where arr[j] - j is the minimum. Then just swap element i with j. This is O(n).

Afterwards you can count the number of swaps you have to do for bubble sort. For this you count all elements which are smaller and to the right of the current element. You can do this in O(n logn) by going from right to left and then for each element you insert it in a balanced sorted tree where you also store the number of nodes in the subtree for each edge (e.g. modified AVL tree). This allows you to count the number of elements which are smaller and to the right of the current one in O(logn).